# Elements with visibility hidden causes white space

Tags: html, css, primefaces

I am facing a case like this, a popup which is hidden using "visibility : hidden" still holds a space in the screen, while I have no control over the coordinates of this element as it's auto calculated by Primefaces control

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/6740jm41/)

here's a simulation for my case

```
<div class="main"></div>
<div class="dialog"></div>
<style>
    .main{
        background-color: red;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .dialog{
        position: absolute;
        top: 800px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        visibility: hidden; 
    }
</style>
```

hope you can help, thank you

Comment: Reproduce your problem in fiddle.

Comment: "display:none;" will remove it from the screen in relation to white space.

Comment: Hope making `display:block;` and `display:none;` will help since `visibility: hidden;` just make the content to hide similar to `opacity:0;`

Comment: So what is the frame work your are using

Comment: @Benjamin http://jsfiddle.net/6740jm41/

Comment: I'm using primefaces, it renderes and hides p:dialog using visibility attribute

Comment: Don't use primefaces then?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat do you think a UI issue is a good reason for rejecting a whole framework ? all frameworks have UI issues and behavior issues as well. Please provide helpful responses

Comment: Maybe I miss something but why can't you show/hide it the normal Primefaces way, eg. PF('wv_dialog').show() and hide() ?

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar I actually call .show() and .hide() and this gives the dialog "visibility:hidden" instead of "display:none"

Comment: @Smartdog If the framework is using the visibility attribute and you can't change it then there must be a reason for it.  It sounds like you can't make it `display: none` in the comments so I don't know what else you can do but switch frameworks to something that will let you do that.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat the project is already live

Answer (score 0):

use jquery to remove the particular element from the screen

```
$( ".dialog" ).remove();
```

Comment: I need to keep the dialog on the screen and hide it without modifing the DOM, an yet I don't need to manipulate framework code, I prefer css solutions